# Doctrine2 Model Attribute based on row position

Tags: sql, doctrine-orm, entity

I have an image object that has multiple ratings linked to that image. What I want to be able to do is get the ranking of that image with regards to other images.

I have managed to generate some SQL that will return the top x images but I am not sure where to start to make it an object attribute.

The ranking calc is the sum of the (rating - 3). Additionally, the primary interface is a REST API with a JSON O/P.

Comment: I realise that isn't the best worded question, but I don't know if that is the question I should be asking.

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, you should not make the ranking calculation and comparing with other images a part of your entity object. It should be outside you entity. Maybe your repository can return an array of ids and its rankings.